# HighStock CandleStick type does not printed in Chrome

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to print a chart [candlestick](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume) type in chrome by clicking native browser print button. This type of the chart is not printed in Chrome. It appears empty
In other browsers it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortnately it is known bug reported by me, here https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1326